# Напечатать двумя циклами числа?

Tags: c++

Как циклом такое напечатать
10
20 20
30 30 30
40 40 40 40
50 50 50 50 50

```
int a = 5;
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << a;
    }
    a++;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: 10 \n 
20 20 \n
30 30 30 \n
40 40 40 40 \n
50 50 50 50 50

Comment: Так "двумя циклами" или "циклом"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <=a ; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << i*10 << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, хорошего вечера)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (unsigned i = 1, j = 0; i < 6; std::cout << ((++j %= i) == 0 ? ++i, "\n" : " "))
  std::cout << i * 10;
```